# Slack Deno SDK development

Tags: slack, deno, bolt

`{ "response_action": "clear" }`

https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals#close_current_view

This is what described about how i might close the modals in my slack app.
Since I am using Deno sdk and operate with views only, i have made use only of the update, open, push methods from client.views object.

How am I supposed to send 200 status to close the modal?

on the client object there is response property with two arguments, where one is url. Where do i get url from?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77889787/edit) the question to include a [mre]?